# RSS Feed in Custom Field

Tags: custom-field, templates, rss

I have a custom field intended for a rss feed. It is simpley a URL in the field, how do I take that url entered and output it into the correct section in the template?

```
<?php include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');wp_rss('<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-rss', true); ?>', 3); ?>
```

Does not work

Comment: Please, try to formulate your Question in terms of *code*, only this description is not enough to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to put this into your template wherever you want to display the RSS custom field:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom field name', true);
```

Comment: This is based on the WordPress codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields